# Is there a way to remove leading spaces from a corpus in r?

Tags: r

after removing stopwords I found many entries having a whitespace at the beginning. Is it possible to remove the leading whitespace where there is one from a VCorpus?

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT:

```
corpus<-VCorpus(VectorSource(frasi))

stopwords<-scan("~stopwords.txt", character(), quote = "")

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = "/", replacement = " ")

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus[[1]]$content
```

```
class(corpus)
"VCorpus" "Corpus"
```

When applying trimw(corpus) the corpus becomes "Large Character".
This is what I have done, I am sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your corpus data?

Comment: > corpus[[3]]$content
[1] "ottimi auricolari"                                                                       
[2] " sentono veramente qualità paragonabile hifi"                                            
[3] ""                                                                                        
[4] "note sentite vuol inseriti imfatti canale uditovo pregiudicano funzionamento"            
[5] " chiamate sentono è sufficiente estrarre destro usarlo mic bocca mentte ascolta sinistro"

Comment: `stringr::str_trim()` removes whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lapply combined with trimws

If you want it to be returned as a VCorpus object you can just use the function as.VCorpus later, as it follows:

`corpus2<-as.VCorpus(lapply(corpus, trimws))`

Otherwise:

`corpus2<-lapply(corpus, trimws)`

It applies to both leading and ending spaces

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Doing as you said makes my VCorpus into a Large List.

Comment: then you can use the function as.VCorpus to convert it into a VCorpus object: corpus<-as.VCorpus(lapply(corpus, trimws))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trimws`:

```
corpusdata <- c("ottimi auricolari"," sentono veramente qualità paragonabile hifi","",
                "note sentite vuol inseriti imfatti canale uditovo pregiudicano funzionamento",
                " chiamate sentono è sufficiente estrarre destro usarlo mic bocca mentte ascolta sinistro") 

trimws(corpusdata)
[1] "ottimi auricolari"                                                                      
[2] "sentono veramente qualità paragonabile hifi"                                            
[3] ""                                                                                       
[4] "note sentite vuol inseriti imfatti canale uditovo pregiudicano funzionamento"           
[5] "chiamate sentono è sufficiente estrarre destro usarlo mic bocca mentte ascolta sinistro"
```

Comment: If it's just *leading* spaces, one could use `trimws(corpusdata, which="left")`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't there a way to apply this change directly in the corpus? So that all records have the space removed.

Answer (score 0):

using gsub function from base R

```
corpusNew<-gsub("^\\s+","",corpusCurrent)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Doing this makes my VCorpus into a character arrary.                    
`> summary(corpus)`
   `Length     Class      Mode 
        3 character character`

Comment: I think this should do, need to pass this as function  f<-function(x){
  x<-gsub("^\\s+","",x)
}

corpusdata<-tm_map(corpusdata,f)